# migrate tkinter code to pyqt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to migrate the code below (which is in `tkinter`) to `pyqt`. I am very new to `pyqt`. I could not get much details.

```
import os, sys, time
import os.path
import shutil
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

def enable_():
    # Global variables
    if (var.get()==1):
        E5.config(state=NORMAL)
        E5.insert(0, 1)
        for c in checkbuttons:          
            c.config(state=NORMAL)  
    # disable test selection
    else:
        E5.delete(0, END)
        E5.config(state=DISABLED)
        for c in checkbuttons:          
            c.config(state=DISABLED)

# Select geometry
root.geometry("500x570+500+300")
root.title('Test Configure')
# Global variable declaration
global row_me
global col_me
row_me =9
col_me =0
L1 = Label ().grid(row=0,column=1)  
Label (text='Target IP Address').grid(row=1,column=0)
E4 = Entry(root, width=20)
E4.grid(row=1,column=1)
L1 = Label ().grid(row=2,column=1)
variable = StringVar()
# Check button creation
var = IntVar()
var_mail = IntVar()
# Create check buttons
R1=Checkbutton(root, text = "Enable Test Suite Selection", variable = var, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20, command=enable_)
R1.grid(row=3,column=1)
R2=Checkbutton(root, text = "Send Email", variable = var_mail, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
R2.grid(row=3,column=2)
L5 = Label (text='Number of Loop').grid(row=4,column=0)
E5 = Entry(root, width=5)
E5.grid(row=4,column=1)
E5.config(state=DISABLED)
L2 = Label ().grid(row=21,column=1)
# List of Tests
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.grid(row=24,column=1)
# Reset Button
configbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Reset", fg="black")
configbutton.grid(row=24,column=2,padx=5, pady=0)
# Quit Button
configbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Quit", fg="red")
configbutton.grid(row=24,column=3)
# Submit Button
blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Submit", fg="black")
blackbutton.grid(row=24,column=4,padx=5, pady=0)

#Check buttons for test suite selection
test_suite_name=[name for name in os.listdir(".") if (os.path.isdir(name) and name.startswith('test-') )]
L34 = Label (text='Select Test Suite To Be Executed').grid(row=7,column=1)      
L11 = Label ().grid(row=9,column=1)
row_me =9
col_me =0
checkbuttons = [create_checkbutton(name) for name in test_suite_name ]
for c in checkbuttons:          
        c.config(state=DISABLED)
# initiate the loop
root.mainloop()
```

I have written this code but I am not sure how to make the grid and location for each widget in `pyqt`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        SubmitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        CancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        ResetButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Reset")
        edit1 = QLineEdit()
        edit2 = QLineEdit()
        cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Enable Test suite selection', self)
        cb.move(150, 100)
        #cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)        
        cb2 = QtGui.QCheckBox('Send mail', self)
        cb2.move(300, 100)
       # cb2.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(SubmitButton)
        hbox.addWidget(CancelButton)
        hbox.addWidget(ResetButton)
        hbox.addWidget(edit1)
        hbox.addWidget(edit2)
        hbox.addWidget(cb)
        hbox.addWidget(cb2)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)    

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 650)
        self.setWindowTitle('HMI')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can either do the designing part in your code or through a QT Designer which ships with PyQt4. and some examples can be found in the path `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples` and documentation in the path `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\doc\html\modules.html` if you are using windows. Hope this helps.